# Auto-formatting Code in WebStorm 6 Akin to Sublime Text's Alignment Plugin

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm a long time Sublime Text user but I recently downloaded WebStorm 6 (6.0.2) and I really like it but I haven't been able to find a plugin that matches Sublime's [Alignment Plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) that re-formats my code which I use extensively (yes, I'm *slightly* fanatical about my code formatting).

For example, in Sublime I can take this code block:

```
user : {
  name    : "Bruce Wayne",
  alias   : "Batman",
  favColour : "black",
  dob : "unknown"
}
```

And after using the Alignment keyboard shortcut it becomes:

```
user : {
  name      : "Bruce Wayne",
  alias     : "Batman",
  favColour : "black",
  dob       : "unknown"
}
```

I've looked into the "Reformat Code" option (`Code > Reformat Code...`) but in this case it doesn't do anything to the formatting as Webstorm believes that it's already correctly formatted, which is in fact entirely correct, just not to my personal standards.

So my question is: is there a (fairly) easy way to accomplish this or is there a plugin that you know of available for WebStorm that offers the same/similar functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code formatting settings are configured at **`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | JavaScript`**. The `Reformat Code` is just a command that reformats selection/file accordingly to those rules. The Code Style for JavaScript **has** such option to make such (or very similar) alignment (check "Other" tab)

Comment: That did it for the most part... it still doesn't space completely correctly but it mostly suits my needs.

`Preferences > Code Style > Javascript > Other` then select `On colon` from the drop-down.

Comment: What else is wrong? The JavaScript code style has 3 other tabs with **plenty of settings** -- please check them -- quite likely that option is already there (e.g. **`"Spaces" tab | Other | Before property name-value separator ':'`**)

Comment: This last comment completely satisfies my original alignment problem, so thank you. :) My other problem is with "=" as a separator rather than just ":"... any suggestions? BTW - if you'd like to post any of the above as an "Answer" I'd gladly accept it as the solution. Thanks again LazyOne!

Comment: I'm not really a JS guy (using it occasionally for simple jQuery stuff) and do not understand what you mean by *with "=" as a separator rather than just ":"*. Do you mean **"consecutive assignments"** (it is implemented for PHP). If so -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6277

Comment: Jesus, I hope they implement this as soon as possible...really miss this feature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code formatting settings are configured at **`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | JavaScript`**. The `Reformat Code` is just a command that reformats selection/file accordingly to those rules.

The Code Style for JavaScript has an option to make such alignment:

- `"Spaces" tab | Other | Before property name-value separator ':'` -- ticked
- `"Other" tab | Align object properties` = `On colon`